# Django: Why KeyError: 'pk'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using Django 2.1
I think I have correctly described pk, but an error occurs. Could you tell me why an error occurs and the solution?

```
KeyError at /create/
'pk'
```

According to the error, there seems to be a problem with "get_success_url", but I do not know why.

```
#views.py
class MemoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Memo
    form_class = MemoForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(MemoCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs={"pk": self.kwargs['pk']})
```

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', MemoDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('create/', MemoCreateView.as_view(), name="create"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the URL for the create view doesn't contain `pk`. That's a parameter to pass to the DetailView, but it needs to come from the saved object itself.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})
```